# Gradle plugin naming convention

Tags: plugins, gradle, naming

Is there an unwritten convention (or a written one, I didn't find) how a Gradle plugin for technology XXX would be called? Examples for the two obvious possibilities:

- XXX-gradle-plugin: [license-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin)
- gradle-XXX-plugin: [gradle-cargo-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin)

I think there are good reasons for both naming conventions. In the Maven community the naming [XXX-maven-plugin is recommended](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html), so I currently tend to use this one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no written convention. Personally I prefer gradle-XXX-plugin, to (hopefully) make it clear that it's a plugin for Gradle.

Comment: This answer is a few years old, I was wondering if anything has changes in that space? I noticed a few patterns being used: com.example.some-name, name, some.name, SomeName, some-gradle-plugin, gradle-some-plugin. I can't see any consistency neither here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html nor there https://plugins.gradle.org/.

Comment: @automatictester I think you should look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugin_reference.html, there is some consistency there.